# C# Excel: Issue in copying worksheet from different workbook

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, office-addins, excel-addins

I'm currently trying to copy a worksheet from a different workbook which i succeed by using Copy() and PasteSpecial(). However, I would like to know why the following code does not work even though many solutions online seems to use this approach.

```html
Workbook currBook = Globals.ThisAddIn.GetActiveWorkbook();
Workbook copyBook = Globals.ThisAddIn.OpenWorkbook(Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path + @"\copyFile.xlsm", true, true);

//required worksheet
Worksheet copySheet = Globals.ThisAddIn.GetWorksheet(copyBook, "ToCopy");
copySheet.Copy(currBook.Worksheets[1]);

//close workbook
copyBook.Close();
```

Function used to get specific sheet:

```html
public Excel.Worksheet GetWorksheet(Excel.Workbook book, string sheetName, bool create = false)
{
    foreach (Excel.Worksheet sheet in book.Worksheets)
    {
        //worksheet with name found
        if (sheet.Name == sheetName)
        {
            sheet.Activate();
            return sheet;
        }
    }

    //worksheet can't be found
    if (create)
    {
        Excel.Worksheet sheet = book.Worksheets.Add();
        sheet.Name = sheetName;
        sheet.Activate();
        return sheet;
    }

    return null;
}
```

There is no error from the stated code and the worksheet has been tested to exist. The program simply does not create a copy into currBook

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly, I was just working on something else where this came up...

In order to specify a destination it's necessary to use `Range.Copy`, not `Sheet.Copy`:

```
copySheet.UsedRange.Copy(currBook.Worksheets[1].Range["A1"]);
```

If a destination can't be specified, then Excel puts the data in a new workbook.

Comment: even though your code works, it doesn't seems like the right answer as i did a test by using Worksheet.copy within the same workbook as given by microsoft 
[link] (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/how-to-programmatically-copy-worksheets?view=vs-2017) and it works. so unless it is a weird restriction with copy requiring to be used within a workbook, the code should still work.